# chrome.tabs.onUpdated returning a tab id that doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm tracking tabs as they get updated, and storing every tab in an array. However, sometimes, and only sometimes, an id gets passed that doesn't exist, and I can't figure it out for the life of me. Is this a known chrome bug or am I just missing something? Thanks so much!

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,currentTab){
    //Find the containing window in the array of windows
    var containingWindow = windows.filter(function(currentWindow){
        return currentWindow.id===currentTab.windowId;
    });
    if (containingWindow.length===1){
        containingWindow = containingWindow[0];
        //Find the containing tab (by id) in our list of tabs.
        var containingTab = containingWindow.tabs.filter(function(currentTab){
            return currentTab.id===tabId;
        });
        if (containingTab.length===1){
            console.log("It worked!");
        }
        else{
            //At this point, there's no reason for it NOT to work, but sometimes an id gets thrown that doesn't exist.
            debugger;
            throw "Argh the bug is still there matey! "+containingTab.length+" "+containingTab+" "+tabId;;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Where do you get `windows` from?

Comment: It's an array I've created called 'windows', and windows are added to said array via chrome.windows.onCreate, and tabs are added to a 'tabs' array contained within the object, via chrome.tabs.onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code won't work because the `Window` objects you store in your array on creation are not live versions of those windows but *snapshots*. Their tab lists are not updated.

If you need updated information about the window containing the tab (for whateve reason), you should call `chrome.windows.get`:

```
chrome.windows.get(
  currentTab.windowId,
  {populate: true},
  function(window) {
    /* ... */
  }
);
```

Comment: I know that. That's why I'm utilizing the onUpdate event to update those tabs. However, onUpdate returns tabs that haven't ever existed. For example, for example, I'll have tab 1860, and it will tell me that tab 1862 was updated, when in reality it was tab 1860. It returned the wrong id for that tab.

Comment: I'm explaining an error in the code you presented. The issue you mention may be due to the fact that you don't listen to `onReplaced` event - Chrome sometimes makes prerendered tabs ans swaps existing tabs for them. I assume prerendered tabs don't get `onCreated` events.

Comment: Huh. That might actually be it. I'll take a look at onReplaced. Thanks so much.

Comment: Question is, why do you even need to track a list of all open tabs this way?

Comment: A tab manager. It's better to store and recall them than to wait on Chrome's functions which may take some time :)